# How can I grant access to a Third Party App

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been trying to allow Apps Script access to my google sheets and google calendar as I am trying to have it create an event on the calendar automatically with specific data from a google sheet. I'm fairly positive I have the code right, but every time I try to run it, it says that I haven't granted the app permission to access google, but I have. When I go into "manage 3rd party apps" the only thing you can do is remove or restrict access, not grant it. I've tried to call about a dozen different customer support numbers, but never get an answer.

Comment: Is your Google account a free/consumer account, or is it a paid Workspace account?  Or otherwise?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve].